# file-loader for webpack is not moving the src folder image files to dist folder

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, webpack-file-loader

```
{
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=img/img-[hash:6].[ext]',
      },
```

I added this config into`webpack.config.js` to utilize `file-loader` by add above rule into

```
module: {
    rules: [
```

section, but none of the image files have moved to `dist/` folder, even if I put the image file into `src/images/`. Is there something I missed need to add to the webpack config?

I am following the example from https://julienrenaux.fr/2015/03/30/introduction-to-webpack-with-practical-examples/

By the way, I am using webpack 2... are there different way to config file-loader now?

Here is the whole webpack config file

```
const { resolve } = require('path');

const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const OpenBrowserPlugin = require('open-browser-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './main.js',
    './assets/scss/main.scss',
  ],

  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },

  context: resolve(__dirname, 'app'),

  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    contentBase: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: [
          'babel-loader',
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            'css-loader',
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              query: {
                sourceMap: false,
              },
            },
          ],
        }),
      },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=15000' },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, use: 'file-loader' },
      { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.[ot]tf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream' },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=img/img-[hash:6].[ext]',
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'style.css', disable: false, allChunks: true }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'vendors', to: 'vendors' }]),
    new OpenBrowserPlugin({ url: 'http://localhost:8080' }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use following snippet to require all files under `src/images/` (or wherever your images are located) inside `main.js`:

```
// load assets
function requireAll(r) { r.keys().forEach(r); }
requireAll(require.context('src/images/', true));
```

This will make Webpack to process all the files that are located inside this folder.

Comment: Dude you save my life ! I ran all over the internet and found absolutely all the webpack.config.js settings and this simple funct is enough ! Thks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It says in the example you're following:

> You now can require any image file using `require('./src/image_big.jpg')`;

If you don't import the images somewhere, webpack won't copy them, because it only applies the `file-loader` to the imports it sees and match your rule. You can also import them in Sass with `url` for example:

```
background-image: url('./src/image.jpg');
```

You also have two rules for `.png` and `.jpg`:

```
{ test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=15000' },
{
  test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
  loader: 'file-loader?name=img/img-[hash:6].[ext]',
},
```

Pick one of them. Because now it will apply both, but only one of them is really used, so you end up with two images when the image is bigger than 15kb because `url-loader` will fall back to `file-loader` when the file is bigger than the configured limit.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

I recommend trying the guide referenced above.  Just note that you need to run the following to get it to all to work:

```
npm install --save-dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter
```

In regard to your question, the image in the above example guide is referenced via an `<img>` tag via an html file.  This `<img>` reference is picked up by webpack and the image file is placed in an assets directory that has been created in the output "dist/" folder:

"app.component.html":

```
<main>
    <h1>Hello from Angular App with Webpack</h1>
    <img src="../assets/images/angular.png">
</main>
```

This is their webpack configuration file with their loaders:

"webpack.conf.js":

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: [
                    {
                        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                        options: { configFileName: helpers.root('src', 'tsconfig.json') }
                    } , 'angular2-template-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap' })
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        // Workaround for angular/angular#11580
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
            {} // a map of your routes
        ),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```